# Console App - "Procedure or function has too many arguments specified" on 2nd run

Tags: vb.net, console

I have written a console application to process, read and sort jpeg images from an input folder. The app uses a third party dll to read barcodes on proof of delivery documents, before giving a relevant file name, copying the file and uploading the path of said file to an SQL database. Everything works ok for a single file, but once I have multiple files in the directory and call the insert procedure for the second time, I get the error "Procedure or function has too many arguments specified". I output the parameters to the console and can see no issue, but command fails at the point of execution. Any ideas what's going on here. Thanks. Steve.

```
For Each File As String In Files
        FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(File)
        SourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(SourcePath, FileName)
        Console.WriteLine("Got File " + SourceFile)
        Results = Reader.DecodeFile(SourceFile)
        If Not Results Is Nothing Then
            For Each item As BarcodeResult In Results
                StrInfo = item.BarcodeText
            Next
            DestFileName = StrInfo & Format(Now, "ddMMyyyy-hhmmss") & ".jpg"
            DestFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(SuccessPath, DestFileName)
            'System.IO.File.Copy(File, DestFile, True)
            Console.WriteLine("File " & DestFile & " Created...")
            sqlCon.Open()
            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Consignment_id", SqlDbType.Decimal)
            sqlCmd.Parameters("@Consignment_id").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            sqlCmd.Parameters("@Consignment_id").Value = StrInfo
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Path", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            sqlCmd.Parameters("@Path").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            sqlCmd.Parameters("@Path").Value = DestFile
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Doc", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            sqlCmd.Parameters("@Doc").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            sqlCmd.Parameters("@Doc").Value = "POD"
            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@UploadedBy", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            sqlCmd.Parameters("@UploadedBy").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            sqlCmd.Parameters("@UploadedBy").Value = "SYSTEM"
            Console.WriteLine(sqlCmd.Parameters("@Consignment_id").Value.ToString)
            Console.WriteLine(sqlCmd.Parameters("@Path").Value.ToString)
            Console.WriteLine(sqlCmd.Parameters("@Doc").Value.ToString)
            Console.WriteLine(sqlCmd.Parameters("@UploadedBy").Value.ToString)
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            sqlCon.Close()
            Console.WriteLine(StrInfo & " Uploaded...")
            'System.IO.File.Delete(SourceFile)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Else
            'DestFileName = FileName
            'DestFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(FailPath, DestFileName)
            'System.IO.File.Copy(File, DestFile, True)
            'System.IO.File.Delete(SourceFile)
            'Console.WriteLine("Failed, moved to 'Bad' folder...")
        End If
    Next
    Console.WriteLine("Finished, press any key to exit...")
    Console.ReadKey()
```

Comment: You dont need to `Add` parameters for each file, just the first one.  Just change the `Value` for subsequent ones.

Comment: Thanks Putonix, this has done the trick. Moved the add parameter rows above the loop and it's now working.